# Image Responsive & Centered Horizontal with a Background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a header on top of my HTML page containing the following HeaderTitle image.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap in order to get my images responsive (img-responsive) as well as to have the Image centered horizontal (center-block).

What I need is to add the following BACKGROUND Image (HeaderBack.jpg):

[image]

behind the HeaderTitle Image so when HeaderTitle got resize the background is filled all wide like this:

[image]

What should I add to the following html/bootstrap code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <a href="/Default.aspx"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/imgs/HeaderTitle.jpg" width="460" height="113" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to create another div around the image, and add the background to that div. (Alternatively, if you want the whole thing to be clickable, you could just set the link to display: block and apply these styles to the link)

Then, apply the background to the container div and put the img inside it. Here's an example:

```css
.header-bg {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYTEF.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="header-bg">

  <a href="/Default.aspx">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACYHO.jpg" />
  </a>

</div>
```

Then you can put that into whatever .container or .row you need to.